# Git fork no longer automatically merges

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a repo (hosted on Github).

There is a fork of my repo. That fork is sometimes updated.

Upon a pull request from their repo to mine, GitHub no longer offers an automatic merge - it seems to me that the two repos have divereged in history.

Am I missing something? The forker has told me that they have pull my most recent changes before performing a pull request.

Comment: Since this question is not about programming, but the github UI, it belongs on our sister site [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Unless your work is secret, you should also include a link to the pull request so that potential answerers can check out the situation.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the pointer to webapps, I hadn't seen it. Yes, it is a private repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have pushed your most recent changes to github, and the forker has fetched *and merged* them, *and* pushed the result back, an automatic merge should be possible. I strongly suspect that one of you left one of these steps out.

You can simply pull the changes in and merge them yourself with:

```
git pull git://github.com/forker/project.git
```

Comment: Wait a second, isn't a pull shorthand for fetch+merge? Why do that extra merge? And thanks for the fix, by the way.

Comment: @eoinoc Yes, of course it is. I had fetch in a temporary revision, and confused that. Should be fixed by now. It's generally a good idea to fetch, *examine the contents of the remote repository*, and then merge.